# How do I select column value based on other column

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Hi Right now I am using this code in my MVC project :

```
AppHistory history = new AppHistory();
 history = (from AppHistory app in Market.AppHistories
        where app.HistoryID == 11
        select app).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

Here I am passing value for app.historyID as 11. In my SQL, this is primary key identity specification. I have userID which I am storing for current users.

So what i should do is instead of passing hardocoded value to app.HistoryID, i need to pass userID parameter here and have to select app.HistoryID based on that userID.

How can i do this?

**Update :**
My table design is shown below. I was not able to upload snap so I am writing my design below:

```
 ColumnName              DataType         AllowNulls
 HistoryID(Primary key)   int              No
 userUID                  int              Yes
 HistoryUserActive        int              yes
 HistoryInactiveFrom      int              yes
 HistoryStart             datetime         yes
 HistoryMonthCost         int              yes
```

**Update 2:**

Can i do like this to check column name based on userID :

```
       int userId = userID 
        history = (from AppHistory app in termsAccepted.AppHistories
   where app.UserID == userId
   select app).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now I need to check whether user has historyID, that is hitory.historyID. For this i need to write if condition like :

```
 if (history.historyID exists)
  {
 //
 }
```

Here what code i should write to check historyID exists or not?

Comment: What is the relationship between user and app? Can you show your class/table structure?

Comment: @kaf userID is ID which every user has and I need to select History ID for that particular user. both values are different.

Comment: You would have already got an answer if you had shown table structure and their relations.

Comment: @kaf you mean i need to take snap of my table and upload here?

Comment: @kaf is right... just share the relationship where UserID is included and the relationship between that table and your history tables... we could help you with more precision.... but... if the only thing you need is to know if the query has results... with the code you shared... you just need to do `if (history)` ... `FirstOrDefault()` will return null if no record is found. Hope this helps a bit... still would be better to have the relationship, I think you could solve this elegantly with a `join`